# Like inside a count SQL

Tags: sql

I want to use a Like Inside a Count So i can take the Number of (in this example) number of active Volunteers along side the VolunteerFundersID

Here is what i have although something tells me I'm going completely the wrong way about it .

```
select
    VolunteersFunderID,
    Count( VolunteerCategory LIKE '%Active%' ) as NumberActive
from
    VolunteerTbl
group BY
    VolunteersFunderID
```

I'm new to using this website and any feedback that isn't insults (I got the last time i posted) would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `%Active%`? The `LIKE` operator performs very slowly when doing a suffix search (`%Active` or `%Active%`) instead of a prefix search (`Active%`). Would an exact text match (` VolunteerCategory = 'Active'`) work?

Comment: In standard SQL you could do: `Count(*) filter (where VolunteerCategory LIKE '%Active%') as NumberActive` - Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this and you need to choose what works best for your scenario.

```
select VolunteersFunderID,
    Count(CASE WHEN VolunteerCategory LIKE '%Active%' THEN 1 END) as NumberActive
from VolunteerTbl
group BY VolunteersFunderID
```

This will go through all rows and count any record where VolunteerCategory is Active. This way, you can count for more categories if you need to do so and put additional conditions etc because you are looking at the full data set.

Another way is to filter the data using a `WHERE` clause:

```
select VolunteersFunderID,Count(1) as NumberActive
from VolunteerTbl
WHERE VolunteerCategory LIKE '%Active%'
group BY VolunteersFunderID
```

Using the WHERE clause, you are filtering your data before you calculate anything so its harder to do other computations.

Comment: You can elide the `ELSE NULL` part because a `CASE WHEN` statement defaults to `NULL` if no `ELSE` statement is provided.

Comment: @Dai Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late Follow up but if i were looking to only return results where the 'Active' Variable is more than or equal to a number how would i do so ? Eg. Greater than 2? Thanks for the help it's really appreciated!

Comment: Thank you ! Genuinely hadn't seen it before!

Comment: @clinomaniac Thanks for copying my answer, worth more than points :)

Answer (score 0):

Move it inside `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT VolunteersFunderID, COUNT(VolunteerCategory) AS NumberActive
FROM VolunteerTbl
WHERE VolunteerCategory LIKE '%Active%'
GROUP BY VolunteersFunderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is aggregate function, so it "counts" only not NULL values. Knowing that you can use `CASE` to make `NULL` and `NOT NULL` values to count only active one.

Query below should work:

```
select VolunteersFunderID, 
    Count(
          case when VolunteerCategory LIKE '%Active%' 
              then 1 
              else NULL
          end
    ) as NumberActive
from VolunteerTbl
group BY VolunteersFunderID
```

It is worth mentioning:

- using `like` with wildcard `%` at the beginning makes query slower - are you sure you cannot just write `VolunteerCategory = 'Active'` ?
- are you sure that other values in that field will not interfere with your "like condition"? I could imagine other `VolunteerCategory` e.g. `InActive`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , all help is appreciated , in this specific instance the percentages don't really matter because there is no other use of the word Active like     'InActive'    . Oddly enough they're all 
   'Part Time'   or     'Silver'    but i'll take your advice and switch it over to just 'Active' . It turned out I was over complicating everything but I learned allot in this thread and I'm great full for all the help . Thank you !